# Angularjs jsonp on static files

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jsonp

I'm getting a CORS issue when downloading a static file from our AWS S3. I'm aware that S3 can be configured to support CORS. However, I also want to learn and know how AngularJS' jsonp works. I've looked at few examples and I'm still confused on the url it is calling.

```
var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data.found);
});
```

If let's say my AWS S3 file is at http://www.amazon.com/S3/sample.jpg, how will I call it with $http.jsonp?

Comment: you can't use jsonp unless server is prepared to deliver jsonp. Also note that image link is not valid

Comment: Ah, that's what I was thinking. Now I'm interested on how to create a jsonp service. Yes, the link was an example only.

Comment: have to wrap the json in javacript function syntax where the function name is the value of `$_GET['callback']`. Is easily researched